# Haskell - parse error on input

Tags: haskell

I have just started using Haskell interpreter.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code:(for Fibonacci)

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib n
|n==0 =0
|n==1 =1
|n>1  =fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

I am getting this error message:

```
 fib.hs:3:1: parse error on input `|'
 [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( fib.hs, interpreted )
 Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indent the next lines at least one space, e.g.:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib n
 |n==0 =0
 |n==1 =1
 |n>1  =fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Haskell is indentation sensitive.  In particular the `|`'s need to be indented further than the function name:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib n
  |n==0 =0
  |n==1 =1
  |n>1  =fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

Also, it is more idiomatic to use pattern matching for comparing with a constant:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 =0
fib 1 =1
fib n
  |n>1  =fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

Comment: Do we need the guard in the last declaration?

Comment: @ssm Not strictly, but it gives a faster error on attempts to call it with negative numbers. I really just left it in because it was in the original.